# How to write Client side(Android json code) for scaffolding ROR?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

I have ROR scaffolding server side code,now i dont know how to write client side code in android json.
My scaffold o/p is [http://localhost:3000/hotels][1] and it displays like this

**Listing hotels
Name    Stars

Baglione    5   Show    Edit    Destroy
Motel   2   Show    Edit    Destroy
Tajimahal   4   Show    Edit    Destroy
Il Melgio   2   Show    Edit    Destroy
Bestia  5   Show    Edit    Destroy
New Hotel**

How can i write this one android using json.

This is the server side code using json in ROR

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /hotels
  # GET /hotels.json
  def index
    @hotels = Hotel.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotels }
    end
  end

  # GET /hotels/1
  # GET /hotels/1.json
  def show
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotel }
    end
  end

  # GET /hotels/new
  # GET /hotels/new.json
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotel }
    end
  end

  # GET /hotels/1/edit
  def edit
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /hotels
  # POST /hotels.json
  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(params[:hotel])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hotel.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hotel, notice: 'Hotel was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @hotel, status: :created, location: @hotel }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @hotel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /hotels/1
  # PUT /hotels/1.json
  def update
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hotel.update_attributes(params[:hotel])
        format.html { redirect_to @hotel, notice: 'Hotel was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @hotel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /hotels/1
  # DELETE /hotels/1.json
  def destroy
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    @hotel.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to hotels_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can u explain it using json format so that we can help u?

Comment: ya,using json format in server side code only,i dont know how to write code in client side

Comment: Why can't you use AsyncTask for retrieve the data from database...

Comment: actually its in scaffolding of ror,i dont know how to take that one in android?@OneManArmy